# Angular2 onclick in ngfor

Tags: javascript, angular, ngfor

Trying to output a function call with click during ngFor. I'm not sure how to reference it.

I'm new to angualr2, and I'm not sure if this is the correct way to achieve this. I would appreciate any advise.

```
export class Navbar {

    constructor() {}

    public userNavs = [
        { title: 'Account', click: 'account()'  },
        { title: 'Logout', click: 'logout()'  }
    ]

    logout() {
        console.log('working');
    }

    account(){
        console.log('working');
    }

    ngOnInit() {}
}

////HTML////

<ul class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right" aria-labelledby="userdropdown">               
    <li *ngFor="let nav of userNavs" ><a class="dropdown-item btn-sm" (click)="{{ nav.click }}" >{{ nav.title }}</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: It's really unclear from your description and the code what you are trying to achieve, It looks like a mess.

Comment: Don't use interpolation within output property `(click)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

that is a better way:

```
    export class Navbar {

    constructor() {}

    public userNavs = [
        { title: 'Account', click: 'account()'  },
        { title: 'Logout', click: 'logout()'  }
    ]

    eventClick(userNav){
      if('Account') this.account();
      else this.logout();
    }

    logout() {
        console.log('working logout');
    }

    account(){
        console.log('working account');
    }

    ngOnInit() {}
}

////HTML////

<ul class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right" aria-labelledby="userdropdown">               
    <li *ngFor="let nav of userNavs" ><a class="dropdown-item btn-sm" (click)="eventClick(nav)" >{{ nav.title }}</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Awesome, this looks much better! Thanks